# How sort array but before find numbers in string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, typoscript

I want to sort my items by Title. My title has a number and if I put default sorting my titles look like this: 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 20, 21
Expect result 1, 2, 10, 11, 12, 20, 21

Me title looks like `E01 how to...`,  `E02 how to...`, `E20 how to...`

my code

```
export interface Tag extends StoryblokComponent<string> {
  text: string;
  color: string;
}

type PodcastContent = {
  heading: string;
  subHeading: string;
  tags: Tag[];
  fullSlug: string;
  image: StoryblokAsset;
  podcastSrc: string;
};

type PodcastsBlok = {
  heading: string;
  disableMarginTop: boolean;
  link: StoryblokSimpleLink;
  linkText: string;
  podcasts: (StoryData<PodcastContent> & { default_full_slug: string })[];
};

export type SerializePodcasts = (PodcastProps & {
  id: string;
  podcastSrc: string;
  publishedAt: Date;
})[];

export const serializePodcasts = (podcasts: PodcastsBlok["podcasts"]) =>
  podcasts
    .map((item) => {
      const isStory = typeof item === "object";
      if (isStory) {
        const {
          uuid,
          published_at,
          content: { tags, heading, image, subHeading, podcastSrc },
          default_full_slug,
        } = item;

        return {
          publishedAt: new Date(published_at as string),
          id: uuid,
          heading,
          subHeading,
          tags: tags.map(({ _uid, color, text }) => ({
            id: _uid,
            color,
            text,
          })),
          podcastSrc,
          image: storyblokImageToMetadata(image),
          fullSlug: default_full_slug,
        };
      }
      return null;
    })
    .filter(Boolean)
    .sort(
      // @ts-ignore
      (a,b) => (b.heading < a.heading ? -1 : 1)
    ) as SerializePodcasts;



export type { PodcastsBlok, PodcastContent };
```

As I understand I should find a number in a string and perform sorting based on the result.  How do I do it with my code?

Comment: So title looks like "1 book mr bookface"? Or is it like just "1"? Examples of titles would help clear the uncertainty in the question.

Comment: added to description

Answer (score 1):

Use regex to find a number inside the string

```js
const data = ['E01 how to...', 'E02 how to...', 'E20 how to...']

const sorted = data.sort((a, b) => {
  const aNumber = Number(a.match(/\d+/))
  const bNumber = Number(b.match(/\d+/))

  return aNumber - bNumber
})

console.log(sorted)
```

Comment: but, `Number('1test')` is NaN

Comment: How could I know how this data looks like?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I read `My title has a number in it` but actually OP said `My title has a number`

Comment: Well if it is a string and number starts it would be just switch to parseInt().

Comment: Me title looks like `E01 how to...`,  `E02 how to...`, `E20 how to...`